# Conformal supergravity or local tensor calculus?

Tags: supergravity, superconformality

What are the pros and cons of the two formalisms? In particular for explicit calculations of components.

Are there textbooks providing self-contained, detailed description of superconformal formalism? Like Wess &  Bagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a book "Supergravity" by Daniel Freedman and Toine Van Proeyen. The book discusses the superconformal formalism in great detail, and show explicitly the construction of four dimensional N=1 and N=2 supergravity theories and their matter couplings.